# How do I make this into multiple matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my string:

```
{1}I still don't know what I was{1} waiting for And my
```

I want to have two matches:

```
{1}I still don't know what I was
{1} waiting for And my
```

But of my regex is selecting everything as one match.
This is my regex:

```
/\{\d+\}.*/g
```

How do I make this into multiple matches?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it ok if the match stops at { or } ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
\{\d+\}.*?(?=\{\d+\}|$)
```

`*?` is lazy, so it will stop matching as soon as `{\d+}` or `$` (end of string) is in front of it.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Vzk3w/1)